# i am getting an error wile compiling my source code in GWT compiler."No source code is available for type com.reveregroup.gwt.imagepreloader.FitImage"

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

/*"No source code is available for type com.reveregroup.gwt.imagepreloader.FitImage; did you forget to inherit a required module?"
*/

```
Canvas left1 = new Canvas();
left1.setAutoHeight();
left1.setWidth(75);

FitImage img = new FitImage();
img.setUrl("/animals/Baboon.jpg");

img.setMaxSize(75, 50);
left1.addChild(img);
```

Comment: Did you include ImagePreloader.gwt.xml in your module file?

Comment: Yes i have included it. @MartijnWijns

Comment: Then I guess you also added the gwt-image-loader jar to the build path, right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. i have added the jar file and also imported the class in my .java file. @MartijnWijns

Comment: Can you describe the environment in which you get the error message? (IDE, how do you build, etc.)

Comment: i am using Eclipse (Juno) and using GWT Compiler Project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71554/discussion-between-rahul-gulwani-and-martijn-wijns).

Comment: Can you put the solution to your problem as an answer to your own question? Other people with the same problem might benefit from it in the future.

Comment: add
 <inherits name="com.reveregroup.gwt.imagepreloader.ImagePreloader" />
in your gwt.xml file

Answer (score 2):

add:

```
<inherits name="com.reveregroup.gwt.imagepreloader.ImagePreloader" />
```

in your gwt.xml file